# how can i convent code from python 3.11 to 2.7

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have some code in python 3.11 and I want to convert it to python 2.7
I tried running the code I made in 3.11 to 2.7 but it had some errors
this is the code:

```
import os
from datetime import date
from tkinter import *
import traceback
import time

with open("log.txt", "w") as log:  # logging an error if it happens
    try:
        today = date.today()  # getting date
        d4 = today.strftime("%Y")  # setting d4 only as current year


        def monthfolcreate():  # creating month folders
            newpath = fr'{a}\January'
            if not os.path.exists(newpath):
                os.makedirs(newpath)

            newpath = fr'{a}\February'
            if not os.path.exists(newpath):
                os.makedirs(newpath)

            newpath = fr'{a}\March'
            if not os.path.exists(newpath):
                os.makedirs(newpath)

            newpath = fr'{a}\April '
            if not os.path.exists(newpath):
                os.makedirs(newpath)

            newpath = fr'{a}\May'
            if not os.path.exists(newpath):
                os.makedirs(newpath)

            newpath = fr'{a}\June'
            if not os.path.exists(newpath):
                os.makedirs(newpath)

            newpath = fr'{a}\July'
            if not os.path.exists(newpath):
                os.makedirs(newpath)

            newpath = fr'{a}\August'
            if not os.path.exists(newpath):
                os.makedirs(newpath)

            newpath = fr'{a}\September'
            if not os.path.exists(newpath):
                os.makedirs(newpath)

            newpath = fr'{a}\October'
            if not os.path.exists(newpath):
                os.makedirs(newpath)

            newpath = fr'{a}\November'
            if not os.path.exists(newpath):
                os.makedirs(newpath)

            newpath = fr'{a}\December'
            if not os.path.exists(newpath):
                os.makedirs(newpath)


        def monthcreate():  # creating all date folders
            jan = 0
            feb = 0
            mar = 0
            apr = 0
            may = 0
            jun = 0
            jul = 0
            aug = 0
            sep = 0
            oct = 0
            nov = 0
            dec = 0

            for i in range(31):
                jan = jan + 1
                newpath = fr'{a}\January\{jan}-1-{d4}'
                if not os.path.exists(newpath):
                    os.makedirs(newpath)

            for i in range(28):
                feb = feb + 1
                newpath = fr'{a}\February\{feb}-2-{d4}'
                if not os.path.exists(newpath):
                    os.makedirs(newpath)

            for i in range(31):
                mar = mar + 1
                newpath = fr'{a}\March\{mar}-3-{d4}'
                if not os.path.exists(newpath):
                    os.makedirs(newpath)

            for i in range(30):
                apr = apr + 1
                newpath = fr'{a}\April\{apr}-4-{d4}'
                if not os.path.exists(newpath):
                    os.makedirs(newpath)

            for i in range(31):
                may = may + 1
                newpath = fr'{a}\May\{may}-5-{d4}'
                if not os.path.exists(newpath):
                    os.makedirs(newpath)

            for i in range(30):
                jun = jun + 1
                newpath = fr'{a}\June\{jun}-6-{d4}'
                if not os.path.exists(newpath):
                    os.makedirs(newpath)

            for i in range(31):
                jul = jul + 1
                newpath = fr'{a}\July\{jul}-7-{d4}'
                if not os.path.exists(newpath):
                    os.makedirs(newpath)

            for i in range(31):
                aug = aug + 1
                newpath = fr'{a}\August\{aug}-8-{d4}'
                if not os.path.exists(newpath):
                    os.makedirs(newpath)

            for i in range(30):
                sep = sep + 1
                newpath = fr'{a}\September\{sep}-9-{d4}'
                if not os.path.exists(newpath):
                    os.makedirs(newpath)

            for i in range(31):
                oct = oct + 1
                newpath = fr'{a}\October\{oct}-10-{d4}'
                if not os.path.exists(newpath):
                    os.makedirs(newpath)

            for i in range(30):
                nov = nov + 1
                newpath = fr'{a}\November\{nov}-11-{d4}'
                if not os.path.exists(newpath):
                    os.makedirs(newpath)

            for i in range(31):
                dec = dec + 1
                newpath = fr'{a}\December\{dec}-12-{d4}'
                if not os.path.exists(newpath):
                    os.makedirs(newpath)


        def submit():  # submit button command
            global a
            a = e.get()
            if os.path.exists(path=a):
                w.config(text="Folder already exists cant make one!.")
                window.after(2000,window.update())
                exit()
            monthcreate()
            window.after(1000, window.update())
            monthfolcreate()
            w.config(text="Folders Created.")
            window.after(2000, window.update())
            exit()


        # creating window
        window = Tk()
        window.eval('tk::PlaceWindow . center')
        window.resizable(False, False)
        window.geometry('300x200')
        window.title('Folder creator')
        window.config(bg='#111111')
        p1 = PhotoImage(file='icon.png')
        window.iconphoto(False, p1)

        # text on screen
        w1 = Label(window, text='Insert folder name or directory:')
        w1.place(x=30, y=50)
        w1.config(bg='#111111')
        w1.config(fg='white')
        w1.config(font=('Arial', 13))

        # 2nd text on screen
        w = Label(window, text='')
        w.place(y=500, x=4030)
        w.pack(side=BOTTOM)
        w.config(bg='#111111')
        w.config(fg='white')
        w.config(font=('Arial', 13))

        # submit button
        submit = Button(window, text="Start", command=submit)
        submit.place(y=130, x=120)
        submit.config(bg='#111111')
        submit.config(fg='white')
        submit.config(font=('Arial', 13))

        # entry box
        e = Entry()
        e.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=CENTER)
        e.config(font=('Arial', 20))
        e.config(bg='#111111')
        e.config(fg='white')

        window.mainloop()

    except Exception:
        traceback.print_exc(file=log)
```

it runs fine on python 3.11 but i need it to run on 2.7 and i dont know what to do to run it this are the errors i get when running it on python 2.7 [image: screenshot of errors]

Comment: Don't. Do not use python2.7 anymore. Use another solution

Comment: Python 2.7 is coming up on _three years_ past its extended support period. There are very few valid reasons to use it in 2022-going-on-2023. Python 3 was first released 14 years ago. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: its for my school and the computers run only 2.7

Comment: @590ms, that's very unfortunate. Nobody should be teaching Python using version 2.7 anymore. In any case, your best bet moving forward is to use Python 2.7 while developing your solution. That way you won't have a translation challenge at the end.

Answer (score 0):

python 2.7 does not have f strings, you need to use string format instead.

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#fancier-output-formatting
https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/string.html#custom-string-formatting

e.g.

```
newpath = fr'{a}\June\{jun}-6-{d4}'
```

becomes

```
newpath = '{a}\June\{1}-6-{2}'.format(a, jun, d4)
```

you could use better variable names though

Comment: That's unlikely to be the only issue...

Comment: @Chris, its' the only issue OP has shared with us.

Comment: @ThePhoton, it's the only error message OP has shared, but the question is "how can I convert this code from Python 3.11 to Python 2.7?" I strongly suspect OP won't be happy until every issue is resolved (which isn't what SO is for). I've voted to close the question as too broad.

Comment: that just ouputs  a KeyError: 'a'

Comment: @590ms: each subversion of python came with many many new features of the language. f-string are just one of the numerous new things introduced with version 3.6 for example. And that is just accounting for python3. And you are asking about python2. Which is not just an older version of the language. It is a different language. So, sure, once you'll have corrected f-string error, you'll see another error, then another, then another. We can go back and forth, we telling you how to correct any error, and you telling us what new error you see. Even if we play that game 24/24 with short reaction...

Comment: @590ms ...time, we are very likely to be still playing that game in 2023. Just check release notes of all python version since python3. And line in those releases notes are potential "retrofiting" you'll have to do. And, again, that is just to make your code run with python3.0. Then you'll still have to make it work with python 2.7

Comment: ok then i should not continue this

Comment: @chrslg ok thx for the advice if there any way i can close this thread?

Comment: @590ms if your code is really small, then it may be shorter, of course (but on the other hand, with libraries you may also end up in dead-end). For closing, no, I don't know. I've never used the question interface, so I don't know if and how you can close a question yourself (I've never encounter a question "closed by asker", so I surmise you can't. I know you can delete it, but it doesn't seem necessary to me — tho, I am quite new around here)

Comment: @590ms, the iteration chrslg is describing is something that you can do yourself. Instead of posting the entire program here and asking how to make it work with Python 2.7, tackle one problem at a time. You have an error message about f-strings. Search the error message, find the solution, alter your code. Now, move on to the next error. Most (all?) of the errors you find are likely to be solvable by searching the error message. If you get a _specific_ problem that you can't find an answer to, feel free to post here. But ask about that specific problem, with as little code as possible.